# How to replace a loop that looks at previous value with a formula in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, formula

**My Problem**

I have a loop that creates a column using a combination of either a value from another column or the previous value in the column depending on a condition ("days from new low = 0"). It is really slow over a huge dataset so I wanted to get rid of the loop and find a formula that is faster.

**Current Working Code**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

csv1 = pd.read_csv('stock_price.csv', delimiter = ',')
df = pd.DataFrame(csv1)

for x in range(1,len(df.index)):
    if df["days from new low"].iloc[x] == 0:
        df["q"].iloc[x] = df["RSI on new low"].iloc[x]
    else:
        df["q"].iloc[x] = df["q"].iloc[x-1]

df
```

**Input Data and Expected Output**

```
RSI on new low,days from new low,q
29.6,0,29.6
29.6,1,29.6
29.6,2,29.6
29.6,3,29.6
29.6,4,29.6
21.7,0,21.7
21.7,1,21.7
21.7,2,21.7
21.7,3,21.7
21.7,4,21.7
21.7,5,21.7
21.7,6,21.7
21.7,7,21.7
21.7,8,21.7
21.7,9,21.7
25.9,0,25.9
25.9,1,25.9
25.9,2,25.9
23.9,0,23.9
23.9,1,23.9
```

Attempted Solution

I tried to create a formula using the .shift() function but i couldnt get it to work.

Any idea how I might be able to do it?

Cheers!

Comment: or if values differ per row, try`df['q']=np.where(df["days from new low"].eq(0),df['RSI on new low'],df['RSI on new low'].shift())`

Comment: That works! Thank you. How would it work if I wanted to change the IF statement to df["qB"].iloc[x] = (df["RSI on new low"].iloc[x-1] - df["RSI on new low"].iloc[x]) / -df["days from new low"].iloc[x-1] instead of df["q"].iloc[x] = df["RSI on new low"].iloc[x] ?

Comment: that doesnt meet the output you have posted so future readers would be confused, I suggest you pick one of the proposed answers here and ask a fresh question with the new conditions +expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The np.where clause performs a vectorized operation that removes the slow python for loop.

```
import numpy as np  
import pandas as pd  
csv1 = pd.read_csv('stock_price.csv', delimiter = ',') 
df = pd.DataFrame(csv1) 
df['p'] = np.where(df['days from new low'].eq(0), df['RSI on new low'], np.nan) 
df['p'] = df['p'].ffill() 
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    RSI on new low  days from new low     q     p
0             29.6                  0  29.6  29.6
1             29.6                  1  29.6  29.6
2             29.6                  2  29.6  29.6
3             29.6                  3  29.6  29.6
4             29.6                  4  29.6  29.6
5             21.7                  0  21.7  21.7
6             21.7                  1  21.7  21.7
7             21.7                  2  21.7  21.7
8             21.7                  3  21.7  21.7
9             21.7                  4  21.7  21.7
10            21.7                  5  21.7  21.7
11            21.7                  6  21.7  21.7
12            21.7                  7  21.7  21.7
13            21.7                  8  21.7  21.7
14            21.7                  9  21.7  21.7
15            25.9                  0  25.9  25.9
16            25.9                  1  25.9  25.9
17            25.9                  2  25.9  25.9
18            23.9                  0  23.9  23.9
19            23.9                  1  23.9  23.9
```

Comment: @EricLeschinski Thank you for updating my answer. However, is it appropriate tagging it as low quality just because I'm missing the `read_csv` part, which isn't even what I used to develop my code?

Comment: I didn't flag your post, someone else did, your post came up as flagged because it was code-only.  If you leave my edits in, it will likely be saved.  If you want to roll back to your prior code lines, it's fine, but it will likely again be brought up and removed as code-only.  It's up to you.  The entire question is very localized and thus also doesn't meet basic requirements for a good question.  Your call.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can use `where`?

`df['q']= df["RSI on new low"].where(df["days from new low"] == 0).fillna(method='ffill')`

See the documentation for where here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html

Comment: That works, but one must check before that there is no nan value in the input dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *value of "q" from previous row* you can apply a function
to each row and use *value from previous execution* of this function.

One of possible solutions to keep this result is to use an **attribute**
of this function.

So define a function to be applied:

```
def fn(row):
    if row['days from new low'] == 0:
        fn.rVal = row['RSI on new low']
    return fn.rVal
```

Then set *fn.rVal* to whatever initial value you choose:

```
fn.rVal = 0
```

And the last step is to apply this function:

```
df['q'] = df.apply(fn, axis=1)
```

This solution works much quicker than your loop and *iloc*.

Comment: I like this idea, although the use of `global` in this scenario is bad practice. Instead you should make `rVal` an attribute of fn: `fn.rVal = row['RSI on new low']`, and lose the global declaration.

Comment: I changed the answer, according to the suggestion by *rje*. I agree, using of global variables is a bad practice, especially if you have many of them.